# Execution plan timings differ from one platform to another

Tags: postgresql, performance, timing, sql-execution-plan, postgresql-9.6

We migrated our production from and old infrastructure to a new one (with new network / servers / dc...).

New hardware / storage are supposed to be at least equal or better (as it is new, with no quality downgrade, compared to old hardware which is 5yo or older).

What is equal:

- postgres release: 9.6.21
- postgres parameters
- RAM : > 180GB
- hugepages: same
- transparent hugepages: none

What differs:

- OS release (before: rhel6, after: rhel7)
- Storage (before: fiber channel, after: iscsi)
- Architecture (before: 1 master + 1 async slave, after: 1 master + 1 sync slave + 1 async slave)
- CPU: same cache but different cycles (before: 3199MHz, after: 3600MHz)

We notice queries are a bit slower.
We started to bench locally to exclude network layers and still observe a difference between before and after.
We tested a simple

```
\timing on
explain analyze select version();
```

and here too, surprisingly, we also have differences.
before:

- planning time avg: 0.005ms
- execution time avg: 0.006ms
- timing avg: .090ms

after:

- planning time avg: 0.016ms
- execution time avg: 0.018ms
- timing avg: .255ms

I also tested with only local disks to exclude storage / iscsi / fc layer and still.
Furthermore, I did the tests on the async slave each time (bench queries are only SELECTs).

How can this be explained ? Which would be the leverages we can use to retrieve previous performances at least locally?

I was thinking about potential specific tuning for PG on RHEL7 or smth related to memory?

Comment: Your query does not really measure query performance. It measures how fast you can plan a function that returns a constant. It does not access any data. You left out any specifics about CPU. Is this on premise or is this cloud?

Comment: Did you `ANALYZE` the database  on the new install in order to update the statistics tables?

Comment: Actually, we started benching accessing data, either going through index or forcing fullscan, and only once we noticed the difference we tried this select version() which I assume should be only in-memory.

Vacuumdb has been done.

Not cloud, local tests.

Answer (score 0):

There are really too many factors and little information to determine exactly what is happening.

An educated guess is that this is either due to the change in storage or in the replication.
Synchronous replication can have a impact on performance, especially in a write-heavy scenario.

If you do not have a in-house benchmark, you can use [pgbench](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/pgbench.html). Run it on both servers, with the same parameters.

Use a scaling, -s flag, big enough to create enough load on your servers).

Make sure your benchmarks runs for at least a few minutes (-t and -T flags).

By using the -r flag, you will see a report of the latency for each statement.

By comparing the results of pgbench on the two servers, you should have a pretty good idea of the situation.

If my guess is correct, you will see that the latency of UPDATE/INSERT statements will be higher on the system with synchronous replication.

Another point worth considering is the difference in storage.

Different storage systems may require adjusting the [random_page_cost and seq_page_cost](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/runtime-config-query.html) to perform optimally for your workload.

Comment: There is of course a difference on the write queries like insert or update, but as you say, we expected this. What we did not expect is to have also a difference on pure SELECT queries. Benches have been performed and confirm we're at the double of time on the new infra for pure SELECT queries, whatever if we point onto master or slave